# add black&silence to beginning of a video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Hi I am struggling to add black&silence to the begining of a video with ffmpeg. I did search a lot but they look too complex for me.
Below command is what I find to add black&silence to the end of of video, now how can I tune it to the beginning of a video?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x1080:d=10 -filter_complex [0:v][1]concat -af [0]apad -shortest output.mp4
```

Looks I need to use **adelay** instead of **apad**, below is the command that makes sense to me, but the audio is not delayed.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x1080:d=10 -filter_complex [1][0:v]concat -af [0]adelay=10  output.mp4
```

Here is the input info and ffmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 
ffmpeg version 4.2.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls     --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb     --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab     --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000998, bitrate: 2526 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 2394 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 16k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 124 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Gyan help please

Comment: @llogan help please

Comment: @llogan Hi, I have edited the question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods to do this. The first method is simple and easy but re-encodes the main video. The other method is slightly more complicated but does not re-encode the main video, so the quality is preserved this method will be faster for long videos.

## tpad & adelay filters

Using the [tpad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) and [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]tpad=start_duration=2[v];[0:a]adelay=2s:all=true[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

If your `ffmpeg` is older than version 4.2 then change `adelay=2s:all=true` to `adelay=2000|2000`.

## color & anullsrc filters with concat demuxer

1. Make 2 second black and silence that match the attributes of the input. Using the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) and [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) filters:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=1920x1080:rate=24:duration=2 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -video_track_timescale 16k -shortest black.mp4
   ```
2. Make `join.txt` containing:

   ```
    file 'black.mp4'
    file 'input.mp4'
   ```
3. Concatenate with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

   ```
    ffmpeg -f concat -i join.txt -c copy output.mp4
   ```

Comment: really appreciate your help. I tried the second method, it works great, and with join.txt I can put the black.mp4 anywhere I like.